# How to make discord bot mute user after they say nsfw word 3 times in a row

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot to mute someone when they say an NSFW word three times in a row. I want the message which contains the word to get deleted every-time and on the 3rd try they get muted. I can't seem to do this.

Here is my cog:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

with open('nsfw.txt') as file:
    file = file.read().split(',')


class BadWords(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, msg):
        for word in file:
            if word in msg.content.lower():
                await msg.delete()
                attempts = 0
                attempts += 1

                if attempts == 3:
                    muted_role = msg.author.guild.get_role(783622936837226529)
                    await msg.author.add_roles(muted_role)
                    embed = discord.Embed(
                        title='',
                        description='',
                        colour=discord.Colour.red()
                    )
                    embed.add_field(name=f"✅ {msg.author.display_name} has been muted.", value='Reason: Toxicity')
                    await msg.channel.send(embed=embed)
                    await asyncio.sleep(1800)
                    await msg.author.remove_roles(muted_role)
                    break

                else:
                    pass


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(BadWords(client))
```

Comment: I think `attempts = 0` should be outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `attempts` back to `0` every time someone says a word. Remove that and put `self.client.attempts = {}` under `__init__` and change `attempts += 1` to this:

```py
try: self.client.attempts[msg.author.id] += 1
except KeyError: 
    self.client.attempts[msg.author.id] = 1 #this will only happen the first time
```

then,

```py
if self.client.attempts[msg.author.id] == 3: 
    pass # do your other stuff
```